# How I can add the menu between the items of listview?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, menuitem

I have question, How I can add the menu between the items of listview? Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you would have to make a custom `ListView` to do this.  You would certainly benefit from reading this bit on [Creating Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) and this specific [custom `ListView`](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/).

The approach I would take is to dynamically add a new list element underneath the element that was touched.  Obviously this element would be rendered differently, and that is where the links from above will be helpful.  When a different element is touched, I would remove the current menu element and insert it into the new location (under the most recently touched element).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to make your menu an item of the list and put it where you want.